# How to restore a Wordpress into which another web app was installed

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, url

So I created a database in cPanel to install SMF into for my WordPress website, but I accidentally made my home URL the place to host the forums.  It overwrote my entire website.  I can't access any of the pages anymore without it redirecting me to my SMF forum.  I deleted the database that the forum was connected to and it's just giving me an error now if I try to go to my website.  Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd have to try and restore the files on the top level, most importantly `index.php` and `.htaccess`.

When that is done, you'll have to hope that SMF didn't overwrite any important Wordpress directories. If it didn't, your install should work again.

`index.php` and any other files in the top directory you should be able to copy from a raw Wordpress install.

The only exception is the .htaccess file which contains the routes for pretty URLs (if you use those - if you don't, skip this paragraph). This file has been generated specially for your install. To re-create it, you should be able to access your `wp-admin` directory already, and [update the permalink structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523689/how-can-i-update-my-permalink-structure-in-wordpress).